# div background grows when border is added

Tags: css

I have a banner div with a nested h2 element. When I add a border to the div it appears to grow. But no content has been added to the div. I'm a bit confused. Here is the scenario:

```
<body>
<div id="easel">
    <div class="banner">
        <h2>One Column Layout</h2>
    </div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum totam quidem, corporis veniam excepturi quasi dignissimos dolores repellat voluptatibus nulla quas, qui magnam debitis accusantium quo, explicabo doloremque iste! Quae voluptatum architecto nostrum soluta, nam ipsam repudiandae temporibus vel debitis libero, amet ducimus? Illo voluptatibus eligendi esse nam sit repudiandae.
</div>
```

```
body {
        margin-left: 15%;
        margin-right: 15%;

    }

    #easel{
        background-color: #555;
        width:600px;
        margin: 0 auto;     
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .banner{
        background-color: #557;
        /* border: 1px solid green; */

    }
```

This give the following:[image]

Now add the green border (commented out above) and the background of the .banner div appears to increase:

[image]

I suspect this has something to do with the User Agent adding
-webkit-margin-before values to h2, but don't fully understand what is going on.

Comment: Have you inspect it with the developer tool? It usually tells you where it comes from.

Comment: Yes @TheLazyChap,  the div doen't have any margin or padding. Only the border is showing as 1px when added and the div the increases in height by 39.831px.

Comment: I pop your code into the browser to have a look, it looks like you were right the -webkit-margin-before and after are adding additional margin to the h2. I saw a 19.920 px of margin for top and bottom. Turning them off kills that.

Answer (score 2):

> **border-box**
>   Length and percentages values for width and height (and respective min/max properties) on this element determine the border box of the element. That is, any padding or border specified on the element is laid out and drawn inside this specified width and height. The content width and height are calculated by subtracting the border and padding widths of the respective sides from the specified width and height properties.
>   http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-css3-ui-20150519/#valdef-box-sizing-border-box

You need to apply `box-sizing: border-box` to the elements

```
#easel, .banner {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: I have added this and there is still no change in the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This must be because of the default margin of `h2` element. Inspect the default margin of the element then assign as accordingly then it will appear to be of your assigned value. Also `box-sizing` property will come helpful if you don't want the banner div to extend by the thinkness of border

Answer (score 0):

Some of the HTML tags like Heading, body etc are taking default margin & padding depends on the browser. So you can use this code for avoid the issue.

```
*{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```